# How to show code diffs with Atlassian Fisheye checkin mails?

Tags: version-control, atlassian-fisheye

Is it possible to configure [Atlassian Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) to show code diff’s in its checkin mails like [svnspam](http://code.google.com/p/svnspam/)

[image]

If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

From the [FishEye docs on customizing emails](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Customising+Email+Notifications) and [Crubicle docs on customizing emails](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/Customising+Email+Notifications) it seems the answer is NO:

"Note that these templates do not support embedding full diffs into notifications. They are only for changing the appearance and order of certain content inside the messages."

Sorry.